# How do I inject properties into MANIFEST.MF with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ear, manifest.mf

I want to add Weblogic-Application-Version to the MANIFEST.MF file of my EAR project. I am imagining IntelliJ can do this via setting some property on some dialog somewhere, or by running a post-build command (shell command I hope) so that I can use jar -m to add the entry.